# Magento 2 : Image stretch and resize not work in cloud server

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I have uploaded two links of images, my localhost server image resize code working fine but does not work on the Magento cloud server-side.

i have use this code :

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image"> <width>700</width><height>700</height><aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio><transparency>true</transparency></image>
```

First pic link : [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTFt.jpg) (i want this image in cloud server)

Second pic link : [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvUNC.jpg) (but actual work in cloud server)

how can I resize an image in the Magento cloud server-side?

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Product images are cached while saving the product from the admin panel. However, sometimes you may need to re-create the product images cache after you import products, if images were resized manually in the cache, or if the cache was manually cleared by mistake.

Command :

> php /bin/magento catalog:images:resize

This command takes no arguments or options. The message Product images resized successfully. displays to confirm the command succeeded.